# creating random pass for a user in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a random password for the user  I create in bash. Here's my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Enter Username you want to add:\c"

read uname

echo -e "Enter Password age:\c"

read page

PSD=`</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c8`

sudo useradd $uname

echo -e "$PSD\n$PSD\n"|passwd $uname

passwd -x $page $uname

echo -e "$uname is created. $PSD is its password and Passwd age is 14 days"
```

It works fine and displays a random pass on the screen, user is created successfully, but the problem is that I can login with that password, means the generated password for the user, doesn't work.

This is just a basic script before I in-cooperate this in 'do while loop' for a program where I'll be creating multiple users and their random passwords and would be redirecting to save them into a text file.
however, before that I'm stuck here, can anyone please point out my mistakes.

P.s, I just started bash a week ago, so sorry if my question sounds stupid to you.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
PSD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c8)
```

**example $PSD**

```
tKJgC4MI
```

**Note:** it is never a good idea to pipe the password from `stdout` to `stdin` from a pedantic security standpoint. Additionally, by `echo`'ing the password twice, you will leave it on `stdin` as only one instance will be consumed by `passwd` (if it will take one at all).

Per the comment and request, here is a script that will implement adding a user with the random password setting password expiration to 14 days. **Note:** the password will expire every 14 days until reset. Also note the use of `useradd` to create the user and set the password:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $UID = 0 ] || {
    printf "\n  error: insufficient permission.\n\n"
    printf "    script must be run as root (uid/euid = 0), user: '%s' can't.\n\n" "$USER"
    exit 1
}

printf "\n  Enter user to add    : "
read uname

printf "  Enter first/last name: "
read fname

printf "  Enter password age   : "
read page

PSD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c8)

cat <<TAG

creating account for:

    name: $fname
    user: $uname
    tpwd: $PSD
    page: $page

useradd -c "$fname" -m -p $PSD $uname

passwd -x $page $uname

TAG

printf "  Create (yes/no): "
read ans

if [ "$ans" = "yes" ]; then
    useradd -c "$fname" -m -p "$PSD" $uname || {
        printf "\n  error: useradd failed.\n\n"
        exit 1
    }
    passwd -x $page $uname || {
        printf "\n  error: setting passwd age failed.\n\n"
        exit 1
    }
    printf "\n  Account successfully created for user: %s\n\n" "$uname"
else
    printf "\n  No account created -- you answered '%s'\n\n" "$ans"
fi

exit 0
```

**use/output:**

```
$ sudo bash uadd.sh

  Enter user to add    : jroger
  Enter first/last name: Jolly Q. Roger
  Enter password age   : 14

  creating account for:

    name: Jolly Q. Roger
    user: jroger
    tpwd: fzMUiCnr
    page: 14

  useradd -c "Jolly Q. Roger" -m -p fzMUiCnr jroger

  passwd -x 14 jroger

  Create (yes/no): yes
passwd: password expiry information changed.

  Account successfully created for user: jroger

$ id jroger
uid=2056(jroger) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but still the same problem.. password is outputted, but it doesn't work for user.. How would you recommend to do this thing?

Comment: `while read line || [ -n "$line" ]       # protect against no newline for last line

do
 name=$line

 pass=$(cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8| head -n 1 >> lol)

   sudo useradd $name -m
  sudo usermod -p $(echo $pass | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) $name

 echo "The user - $name - has been created!" 
 
done < "$fname"                         # double-quote fname

echo`

Hi, I am trying to do like this.. The script runs fine, and saves the password in lol file, but when I try to use these password to login, passwords don't work.. Any help on that?

Comment: @Umair - Ok, I updated the answer and added an example script using the randomly generated password.

Comment: This is amazing.. I have saved your answer for future use.. However, at the moment,  here's what I have done, just posting it in case anyone else find it helpful.

I have used this to generate the random pass `pass=$(cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8| head -n 1)` , then piped it to the text file to know what I'm setting, `echo "$pass" >> lol`
and then setting password for user in loop like that.. `sudo usermod -p $(echo $pass | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) $name`, its working in Ubuntu 14 latest version.  As you mentioned about usermod security lag, I'll Google on it, TY so much!

Comment: Also, how do I run my script as Root, because I have to enter password everything and use sudo..

Comment: Save the script into `somefile.sh` (whatever you like). Make it executable. `chmod 0755 somefile.sh`. Then run the command with `sudo somefile.sh`, it will then prompt you for the root password. You can prevent having to provide a password with `sudo` by adding yourself to the `wheel` group (generally, some use `sudo` group). The add your user to it. `gpasswd -a youruser`. Then, `sudo visudo` to modify the `sudoers` file, and uncomment or add the last line `%wheel  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` (logout/login) you should `sudo` w/o needing a password now.

Comment: Hi, I have done as you said.. saved sudoers file, picture ( `http://i.imgur.com/L6gJhjg.png` ). Logged out and logged back in.. However the `sudo somefile.sh` command doesn't work.. My file, lets say somefile.sh, was already executable, although I run the `chmod 0755 somefile.sh` again.. but it says `no command sudo somefile.sh found`..

Comment: I apologize. I needed to be a bit more literal. When a program or script is not in your `PATH`, you must proceed the name with `./` So the complete command would be `sudo ./somefile.sh`. This is required because the system needs a complete PATH for each executable to remove any ambiguity about what to execute. When a program or script is in your `PATH`, (e.g. in `/usr/bin`) the system automatically prepends the path. When an executable is not in your path, the `./` removes all ambiguity about which file should be executed. Also, you know you can `su root` to become root.

Comment: Thank you so so much for this.. Its working now.. You are amazing.. I cant thank enough for all this help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Bash is a fantastic shell. You can do anything you need to do to administer a Linux box. It is worth the time to learn it. One good guide that helps was the [**Advanced Bash Scripting Guide**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and the [**Bash Reference Manual**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). While they don't cover everything, they provide a good foundation. The `man bash` (all 4132 pages) and `man bashbuiltins` (just the builtin commands like `alias, declare, read, etc.`) are also good.

Comment: You should be aware that passwords can be sniffed by any user who's able to see process list when you use that script. In my opinion Bash is powerful but at the same time it's better to use it to easy things **only**. It has lot of traps. Write something and cross check it with [Bash Pitfalls webpage](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) to see what I mean.

Comment: It is not recommended to pass or pipe a password to `stdout` or between `stdout/stdin`. Keyloggers, the surveillance camera and the guy standing behind you are all possible compromises. It can range anywhere from (it's just my box -- and I'm fine with it..) to (you did what? you're fired..)

Answer (score 1):

This will not work as `passwd` doesn't read input as you think it does. It opens terminal, read input and closes it. If it has to read it two times (to be sure you didn't made a mistake) it does the procedure twice.

You should use `chpasswd` which updates passwords in batch mode.

Comment: `while read line || [ -n "$line" ]       # protect against no newline for last line
do
 name=$line
 pass=$(cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8| head -n 1 >> lol)
   sudo useradd $name -m
  sudo usermod -p $(echo $pass | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) $name

 echo "The user - $name - has been created!" 
 
done < "$fname"                         # double-quote fname

echo`

Hi, I am trying to do like this.. The script runs fine, and saves the password in lol file, but when I try to use these password to login, passwords don't work.. Any help on that?

Comment: `man usermod`: Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes. [..] **This might differ from the password database configured in your PAM configuration**. You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.

Comment: Then how can I do this.. So puzzled.. I tried Googling `chpasswd` for ubuntu, but not getting it .. :/

Comment: Weird.. what Ubuntu version do you have ? I have `chpasswd` on mine (it's part of `passwd` package)

Comment: `apt-cache show passwd`, `dpkg -L passwd|grep chpasswd` ?